# Equivalence Relation Quotient

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I would like to solve Problem 1.7.6 from Dugundji's Topology:

> Let $S$, $R$ be two equivalence relations in $A$, with $S \subset R$. Let $1^* : A/S \to  A/R$ be the map induced by relation preserving map $1_A$. Define $(S a) R/S (Sb)$ if $1^*(S a)=1^*(Sb)$.
>
> Show that $R/S$ is an equivalence relation, and there is a bijection of $(A/S)/(R/S)$ onto $A/R$

Comment: Please reformat your Question as to view mathematical symbols accordingly and show us what you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function then the relation $\sim$ defined
by $x\sim x'\iff f\left(x\right)=f\left(x'\right)$ is *always* an equivalence
relation.

Verification:

reflexive: $f\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)$,

symmetric: $f\left(x\right)=f\left(x'\right)\Rightarrow f\left(x'\right)=f\left(x\right)$

transitive: $f\left(x\right)=f\left(x'\right)\wedge f\left(x'\right)=f\left(x''\right)\Rightarrow f\left(x\right)=f\left(x''\right)$.

The map $\phi:\left(A/S\right)/\left(R/S\right)$ defined by $\left[\left[a\right]_{S}\right]_{R/S}\mapsto\left[a\right]_{R}$
is welldefined and is a bijection.

Comment: Can I ask how to show that Phi is onto please ?

Comment: If $y$ is an element of $A/R$ then $y=[a]_R$ for some $a\in A$. Now note that for  $x=[[a]_S]_{R/S}$ we have $\phi(x)=y$. This shows that $\phi$ is onto.